# Recuperar coluna de um join na view

Tags: codeigniter

Tenho uma consulta com *join* e em ambas as tabelas eu tenho uma coluna com o mesmo nome `ds_observacao`.

As tabelas são: `cliente` e `ordem_servico`.

Na hora de mostrar na *view*, o valor dessa coluna me retorna em branco. Pois está buscando a coluna da tabela `cliente`. Como faço na hora de retornar o valor pra deixar explícito que eu quero da tabela `ordem_servico`?

Já tentei fazer assim na *view*:

```
echo $registros->ordem_servico->ds_observacao;
```

Porém sem sucesso.

Comment: Boa tarde, você conseguiu resolver o seu problema com alguma das respostas? Se sim por favor indique qual marcando o "V" logo abaixo da qualificação da pergunta. Se não nos avise informando seu progresso para que possamos continuar a lhe ajuda-lo.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver utilizando `alias` e especificando as colunas no `select`.

```
$this->db->select ('e.id event_id, e.name event_name, v.id venue_id, v.name venue_name');
$this->db->join('venues v' , 'v.id = e.venue_id');
$query = $this ->db->get( 'events e');
```

Answer (score 2):

Não conheço o CodeIgniter, mas se puder alterar ou escrever diretamente o SQL tente algo semelhante a isso:

```
SELECT 
  c.ds_observacao AS ds_observacao_cliente,
  os.ds_observacao AS ds_observacao_ordem_servico
FROM ordem_servico AS os
  JOIN cliente AS c ON (c.idCliente = os.idCliente)
```

Ou seja usar um alias para se referir aos campos na própria consulta assim na hora de recuperar os campos você irá se referir aos alias e não aos campos em si.